# Saving and retrieving data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post, get

I have an HTML file with an input in which the user can enter his name and another one in which the user can enter his age followed by a button and a List:

```
<p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
<p>drink: <input type="text" id="age"></p>
<button id="post">Submit</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Now I want the values ​​to be saved in a JSON file like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Person 1",
    "age": 54
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "age": 27
  }
]
```

I have a JavaScript file in which I used ajax with jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  var $output = $('#output');
  var $name = $('#name');
  var $age = $('#age');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    success: function(data){
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        $output.append('<li>name: '+item.name+', age: '+item.age+'</li>');
      });
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('error loading items');
    }
  });

  $('#post').on('click',function(){

    var object = {
      name: $name.val(),
      drink: $drink.val()
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'data.json',
      data: object,
      success: function(newItem){
        $output.append('<li>name: '+newItem.name+', age: '+newItem.age+'</li>');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('error saving items');
      }
    });

  });

});
```

But if I run the code on a server, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
```

I checked the JSON code but could not find an error. If I run the code on my localhost, I don't get an error message, but the values ​​are undefined and won't be saved in the JSON file.

Comment: `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'data.json', ... `. Hm. Tell us a little about your "server"? You really need to have one.

Comment: What is the actual value of `data` before you try to parse it? Just to verify, you do have some server the accepts the POST request and modifies a file? You can't just read/write to server files directly, unless you have some server that essentially does just that.

Comment: Remove `data = JSON.parse(data);` and add `dataType:'json'` to ajax options

Comment: Thank you! Now it works getting the data from the JSON file, but my new values ​​are still undefined and they aren't stored in the JSON file.